# Schedule eMails (Reminders) - Automatic eMail Sending

Tags: windows

In the pursuit of becoming more efficient. I'm looking for a piece of software which runs on Windows platform, whereby you can schedule email reminders.

I have felt this software [AMSSE](https://www.automailsender.com/f/schedule-emails.htm) and it is rather overkill for what I want and it is expensive.

Something that really stood out was the ability to schedule sending emails which can be seen below.

[image]

Effective in our objective is to write an email of some sort which is sent to the appropriate people X times a month or year whatever order reminded the individuals to do certain tasks. One could be for example file company accounts, go visit the dentist etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install [Mozilla Thunderbird](https://www.thunderbird.net/en-US/) and its addon [Send Later](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/send-later-3/?src=search).

[image]

Go to: File > New > Message

From message window: File > Send Later

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I have downloaded it, it is an outdated plug-in, I believe it requires version 30 or as we now are on version 60. I will give it a go.

If anyone else is aware of any other application please let me know.

Comment: That's strange! See this [screenshot of Mozilla Thunderbird addon search results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZoGPw.png).

Comment: My bad!!! You are right. I did not have my tea!!!! GREAT solution. Thank you